# Jquery tabs loading spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Anyone know why the spinner in this jsfiddle is not showing at all:

http://jsfiddle.net/bJ9sq/1/

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
      },
        spinner: '<img src="http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif"/>'
    });
  });
```

All my searches say that the spinner option should show an icon when the tab is loading but I never see it here ...

It seems that they may have removed this options ? If so what is the current method of showing a spinner on load of a slow loading panel?

Comment: I scrapped trying to use jQuery UI's inbuilt spinners with tabs, it was inconsistent across browsers and only seemed to work in firefox and occasionally IE, chrome never displayed it. Whether this was fixed in 1.9 I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spinner option was removed two years ago with jQuery UI 1.10 (deprecated in 1.9).

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-spinner-option

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tabs-api-redesign

You'll need to use the beforeLoad event to add your own spinner and the load event to remove it.